# dotnet core database first using NetTopologySuite

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, nettopologysuite

I recently upgraded to the newest version of **EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL** but the spacial data didn't seem to work, because they now use **NetTopologySuite** see [here](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nts.html)

> To set up the NetTopologySuite plugin, add the
>   Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite nuget to your
>   project. Then, make the following modification to your UseNpgsql()
>   line:

I use the `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "MyConnectionString" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL
```

however, the `scaffold` command doesn't seem to use the **NetTopologySuite** mapping. I still get the following error

```
Could not find type mapping for column 'public.behaviour.coord' with data type 'geometry(Point)'. Skipping column.
```

How can I scaffold my database using **NetTopologySuite**

Comment: Maybe that post can help you?
https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/441

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, after updating the postgre library, I had to delete migration files and regenerate new ones

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EFDesignTimeService : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        new EntityFrameworkRelationalServicesBuilder(services).TryAddProviderSpecificServices(x =>
        {
            x.TryAddSingleton<INpgsqlOptions, NpgsqlOptions>(p =>
            {
                var dbOption = new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
                    .UseNpgsql("connection string",
                        ob => ob.UseNodaTime().UseNetTopologySuite()).Options;
                var npgOptions = new NpgsqlOptions();
                npgOptions.Initialize(dbOption);
                return npgOptions;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using the `geometry(Point, 4326)` type 
and I had to change the type to geometry

```
ALTER COLUMN coord TYPE geometry;
```